# Strange indent using tabular in titlingpage

Tags: tables, spacing, memoir

I need to create a simple problem description page for my thesis. This will also be the title page of the document. I'm using the `memoir` class. I tried to use the `tabular` environment to align some fields, but it produces some annoying indentation I'm not able to remove.

Here's an illustration of what I mean

[image]

and here's a minimal working example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlingpage}

\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}l}
Project title:          & Title \\
Student's name:         & Name\\
Problem description:    & \\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{4ex}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
\vspace{4ex}

\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5cm}l}
\noindent Assignment given:     & 01.01.2012 \\
\noindent Supervisor:           & Name\\
\noindent Co-Supervisor:        & Name  \\
\end{tabular}

\end{titlingpage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\noindent` should also precede the `tabular` structures:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlingpage}

\noindent% <----------------- added
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5cm}l}% <--- modified column specification
Project title:          & Title \\
Student's name:         & Name\\
Problem description:    & \\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{4ex}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
\vspace{4ex}

\noindent% <----------------- added
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5cm}l}
\noindent Assignment given:     & 01.01.2012 \\
\noindent Supervisor:           & Name\\
\noindent Co-Supervisor:        & Name  \\
\end{tabular}

\end{titlingpage}

\end{document}
```

A `tabular` starts a paragraph, and therefore also inserts a `\parindent` space. `\noindent` removes it, as expected. Using `\hspace*{-\parindent}` would too.

Comment: I've already tried that. It mitigates the problem somewhat, but a small indent still remains.

Comment: @hakoja: Note the modification in the column specification. The `@{}` removes any intercolumn space, which also shows as a small indent.

Comment: I tried removing that as well :) Look at the first tabular environment in my example, it doesn't contain a `@{}`. And the (small) indent still remains when I use `\noindent`

Comment: Never mind! I messed up, sorry. I edited the wrong document, therefore I didn't see the changes. Your suggestion worked indeed :) Thanks!